# Lotus Notes: From the view, how to insert the column values to the e-mail body content in table or list format

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to know how to insert the column values from the view to the email content and send it?

I have this agent on which it gets the first 10 documents from the view, exports the 10 document's specific column values to an .xls or .ods file. The file then will be attached to the body of the e-mail. Now, I want to also include the list (either in table format or list format) to the body of the content e-mail. What should be the approach to it?

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the approach I describe here: 
http://blog.texasswede.com/dynamic-tables-in-classic-notes/

Basically what you do is to create a form where you lay out the fields you want to display on each row. In your code you then loop through your collection of Notes documents, and for each one you create a row template document, populate the fields in it and render the document as rich text into the body (rich text) field of your email.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [NotesViewNavigator](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESVIEWNAVIGATOR_CLASS.html) class to read the first 10 documents from view with [GetFirstDocument](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFIRSTDOCUMENT_METHOD_VIEWNAV.html) and [GetNextDocument](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETNEXTDOCUMENT_METHOD_VIEWNAV.html). Read the column values with [notesViewEntry.ColumnValues](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COLUMNVALUES_PROPERTY_5887.html).

Write the values into a RichText table. Here is an [example](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_NOTESRICHTEXTTABLE_CLASS.html) how to create and fill it:

```
  Dim body As New NotesRichTextItem(doc, "Body")
  REM Create table in Body item
  rowCount% = 4
  columnCount% = 3
  Call body.AppendTable(rowCount%, columnCount%)
  REM Populate table
  Dim rtnav As NotesRichTextNavigator
  Set rtnav = body.CreateNavigator
  Call rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL) 
  For iRow% = 1 To 4 Step 1
    For iColumn% = 1 To 3 Step 1
      Call body.BeginInsert(rtnav)
      Call body.AppendText("your value from row's column")
      Call body.EndInsert
      Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)
    Next
  Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIME` and generate content of your e-mail by using `HTML` capabilities, for example you can generate this table in your e-mail:

```xml
<table>
   <th><td>Header 0</td><td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td></th>
   <tr><td>Value0 0</td><td>Value1 0</td><td>Value2 0</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Value0 1</td><td>Value1 1</td><td>Value2 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Value0 2</td><td>Value1 2</td><td>Value2 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is example:

```vb
Dim ses As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim coll As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim mailDoc As NotesDocument    
Dim stream As NotesStream
Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
Dim child As NotesMIMEEntity

Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase   

html$={<table>
    <th><td>Header 0</td><td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td></th>
}

'Get your document collection:
'Set coll = ...

'Generate table content:
Set doc = coll.GetFirstDocument

Do While Not doc Is Nothing
    html$ = html$ & {
    <tr><td>} & doc.Field0(0) & {</td><td>} & doc.Field1(0) & {</td><td>} & doc.Field2(0) & {</td></tr>}

    Set doc = coll.GetNextDocument(doc)
Loop

html$ = html$ & {
</table>}

'Generate excel file:
'fileName$ = "SomeFile.xlsx"
'filePath$ = "C:\SomeFolder\" & fileName$

'Create mail document:
Set mailDoc = db.CreateDocument
mailDoc.Subject = subject$
mailDoc.SendTo = mails

ses.ConvertMIME = False

'Add html to mail body:
Set stream = ses.CreateStream
Set body = mailDoc.CreateMIMEEntity
Call stream.WriteText(html$)
Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT)

'Add attachment:
Set child = body.CreateChildEntity 
Set header = child.CreateHeader("Content-Disposition") 
Call header.SetHeaderValAndParams(|attachment; filename="| & fileName$ &|"|) 

Set stream = ses.CreateStream 
stream.Open filePath$, "binary" 
child.SetContentFromBytes stream, "application/octet-stream", ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY
child.EncodeContent ENC_BASE64

Call mailDoc.CloseMIMEEntities(True, "Body")

'Send mail:
Call mailDoc.Send(False)
```